# how to create a flag in R with output in new column

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I have following data frame

`all <- c("a","a","a","a","a","a","a","d","d","d","c","c","c","c")`

I want to create a column which flags entries in data set all as output should be in another column lets say all$call with group of each a's in data all flagged as good ,d's as better ,c's as best

can any one tell me how to do that in r programming. Thanks in advance

Comment: something like: `all$call<-factor(all,label = c('good','best','better'))`

Comment: `all$call <- ifelse(all == "a", "good", ifelse(all == "d", "better", "best"))`

Comment: Thank you @ Niek and Leo P both works for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the  `case_when` function.

Suppose your entry is a vector :

```
entry <- c("a","a","a","a","a","a","a","d","d","d","c","c","c","c")
```

Then you can simply get the output you want in a new vector with :

```
output <- case_when(
  entry == 'a' ~ "good",
  entry == 'd' ~ "better",
  entry == 'c' ~ "best"
)
```

You can find more information on `case_when`at https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dplyr/versions/0.7.2/topics/case_when

Comment: Thank you Quentin